# how to set a div height from its location to bottom of the page, add scrollbar if exceeds?

Tags: html, css

In `html` \ `css`, I've got a `div` element that can appear at different `y positions` of a page (conditional to the populated html above it). Problem occurs when content of the `div` rendered is too tall. In that case I'd like the `div` to expand to at most the page's height (e.g. based on screen resolution) and add a `scrollbar` to match its content.

Is there any pure `html` \ `css` solution for this, without using `js`?

Attached is an example of the div structure. Notice that I'd like to have a scroll inside the big blue div, without tying to a specific height, as I do not know in advance what are the given sizes (they're dynamic).

http://jsbin.com/jaboxoneju/edit?html,output

Comment: If setting .your-div{max-width:100%;overflow-x:scroll;} doesn't work it would be handy if you could put together a JS Fiddle so we can get a better understanding of the layout and code in place already.

Comment: Should the scrollbar be added to the div (so top components will always be visible) or to the page?

Comment: to the div, not to the page . Will get a jsfiddle example

Comment: @vondip Did any of our answers end up working for you?

Comment: Don't know yet. I'll update tomorrow with my findings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a flexbox layout that causes the second div to scroll when its height would exceed the height of the window.

**Live Demo:**

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#upper {
    background-color: red;
}

#scrolling {
    background-color: blue;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="upper"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultricies nisl lacus, sit amet viverra magna scelerisque a. Morbi rutrum quam a tellus fermentum, vel ultricies ligula dignissim. Nam bibendum nisi in metus bibendum, sit amet tristique massa molestie.</p></div>
    <div id="scrolling"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ultricies nisl lacus, sit amet viverra magna scelerisque a. Morbi rutrum quam a tellus fermentum, vel ultricies ligula dignissim. Nam bibendum nisi in metus bibendum, sit amet tristique massa molestie. Quisque pretium arcu non magna pretium, nec fringilla augue pretium. Etiam a tellus ipsum. Curabitur ultrices vel nibh sit amet feugiat. Etiam consequat id ligula eget suscipit. Vestibulum sagittis tincidunt quam porta eleifend. Suspendisse interdum metus et tellus maximus dapibus. Phasellus vel bibendum leo, eu faucibus nisi. Sed vestibulum interdum arcu, et sodales diam cursus vel. Aliquam tristique lorem posuere tortor aliquet, sit amet pharetra lectus tristique. Maecenas consectetur laoreet tellus. Proin interdum tincidunt ex non commodo. Morbi non tristique orci, vel porta ligula. Duis sollicitudin in elit eu laoreet.</p>

<p>Sed volutpat vel tortor id placerat. In nisl odio, ornare at enim sit amet, mollis ultricies libero. Mauris et auctor lorem, in maximus felis. Fusce elementum nisi odio, sed venenatis enim convallis euismod. Sed sed pharetra ligula. Donec venenatis imperdiet turpis, vitae vehicula leo luctus a. Cras ultrices rutrum aliquet. Proin scelerisque nisl vitae posuere consectetur. Sed viverra rutrum nulla ut accumsan. Curabitur posuere consectetur nulla nec cursus. Donec id massa odio.</p></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/9gtLughL/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="overflow:Auto;">
  <h2>my code</h2>
</div>
```

use this code at the start of the div

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a table structure.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container table">
   <div class="table-row">
       Top Content
   </div>

    <div class="table-row height-100">
        <div class="table-cell">
            <div class="height-100">
                <div class="scroll">
                 Bottom scrollable content with 100% remaining height
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table { display:table; }
.table-row { display:table-row; width:100%; }
.table-cell {display:table-cell; height:0; overflow:hidden; }
.container { height:100vh; }
.height-100 { height:100%; }
.scroll { overflow:auto; height:100%; }
```

The `100vh` attributes makes the `body` tag to have 100% of `view height`(screen height).

In a table structure, the div with class `table-row` will get height as much as needed by children, but if it also has `height-100` will get 100% of what the other rows do not occupy. Inside it I did a few ugly twitches to get the overflow running on a dynamic height `table-cell`,

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alexix/70vf92e3/2/